# IRegisteredTask::RunEx not working, and there's no logs?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to execute a scheduled task with a different user, as stated [in this article](https://tyranidslair.blogspot.com/2019/09/the-art-of-becoming-trustedinstaller.html)

I opened powershell in elevated mode (Windows 10 - 1809), and executed the following lines:

```
$a = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute notepad.exe
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'TestTask' -Action $a

$svc = New-Object -ComObject 'Schedule.Service'
$svc.Connect()

$user = 'NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller'
$folder = $svc.GetFolder('\')
$task = $folder.GetTask('TestTask')
$task.RunEx($null, 0, 0, $user)
```

And the output is like this,

[image]

No error, no notepad.exe created in background either.

What was wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your code *does* work, but **requires Windows 10 *Version 1903*** (that it doesn't work in earlier versions may be a bug):

  - It seems that **the problem is specific to the `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller` user account**; the [`IRegisteredTask::RunEx` help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-iregisteredtask-runex) offers no pointers.

    - By contrast, running as `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`, the local system account, works fine on older versions too, including on Windows 7.
  - Note that even when the code does work, the Notepad instance launches *invisibly*, because it runs in the hidden session (with session ID `0`) in which services and scheduled tasks (by default) run; to find all processes running in this session, you can use `Get-Process | ? SessionId -eq 0`; you can also find such hidden processes in Task Manager.

---

**Test code** (should also work on Windows 7) that can be used to experiment with different target programs and user accounts:

Note:

- The code must be run from an ELEVATED ("Run As Administrator") session.
- In my experiments I wasn't able to launch the task with the local system account *visibly*, in the current user's session.

```bsh
$ok = $false
try {

  # Create a scheduled task that launches $targetExe, for testing.
  $taskName = "__TestTask"
  $targetExe = 'notepad.exe'
  $haveCmdlets = [bool] (Get-Command -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue New-ScheduledTaskAction)

  # If creating the task fails, we'll catch it below on trying to retrieve the task.  
  if ($haveCmdlets) {
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $targetExe
    $null = Register-ScheduledTask -Force -TaskName $taskName -Action $action
  }
  else { # before Windows 10: use schtasks.exe
    schtasks.exe /create /tn $taskName /sc once /st 00:00  /tr $targetExe /f *>$null    
  }

  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

  # Connect to the Task Scheduler via COM Automation.
  $svc = New-Object -ComObject 'Schedule.Service'
  $svc.Connect()

  # Get the task to run.
  $folder = $svc.GetFolder('\')                                                             #'#
  $task = $folder.GetTask($taskName)

  # Specify the user account in which the task should run:
  # W10 v1903 and above only:
  $user = 'NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller'
  # NOTE: 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' should work on older systems too.

  # Run the task, which outputs an object representing the running task instance.
  # Note: If the task *itself* can be kicked off, but $targetExe cannot be launched, NO error occurs.
  $taskInstance = $task.RunEx(
    $null,  # parameters to pass (Variant type)
    0,      # 0 == TASK_RUN_NO_FLAGS; use 1 == TASK_RUN_AS_SELF to override the configured user and run as the current one.
    0,      # 0 == default session ID; even when combined with 4 == TASK_RUN_USE_SESSION ID, targeting a different session doesn't seem to work.
    $user   # user name (use $null for the user configured with the task)
  )

  # Show the properties of the newly created task instance.
  Write-Host "-- Launched task: "
  $taskInstance | Format-Table *

  # Give $targetExe some time to start up.
  Start-Sleep 2

  # List all $targetExe processes along with what user account launched them.
  # To limit output to processes running in the hidden "services" session (session ID 0)
  # use:
  #    Get-Process $targetExe | Where-Object SessionId -eq 0 
  Write-Host "-- $targetExe processes: "
  Get-Process ([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($targetExe)) -IncludeUserName | 
    Format-Table Id, Name, Username, SessionId

  $ok = $true

} finally {

  # Clean up.
  $svc = $null

  if ($haveCmdlets) {
    Unregister-ScheduledTask -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue $taskName -Confirm:$false
  }
  else {
    $null = schtasks /delete /tn $taskName /f
  }

  if ($ok) {
    Write-Warning "A launched $targetExe process that doesn't exit by itself will continue to run. If safe to do, kill all existing instances with:`n  Stop-Process -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Name $([IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($targetExe))"
  }
}
```

The above should yield something like the following:

```
-- Launched task:


Name       InstanceGuid                           Path        State CurrentAction EnginePID
----       ------------                           ----        ----- ------------- ---------
__TestTask {E6112AC9-7616-46A1-9514-6344EC445485} \__TestTask     4 notepad.exe        4372


-- notepad.exe processes:

  Id Name    UserName            SessionId
  -- ----    --------            ---------
4372 notepad NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM         0
```

Note that even though it is `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` - not the requested 
`NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller` account - that is the effective user name, only when started as `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller` will the process have the requisite security token to act as the trusted installer.

Comment: Just installed another VM. It works on 1093. The EnginePID field is empty on 1809, sigh.

Answer (score -2):

If you want notepad running as the system user in session 1 so that it's visible on the desktop, you can run notepad with sysinternals psexec from an elevated prompt:

```
psexec -si notepad
```

Comment: I may have created a red herring with the visibility issue, because the question shows awareness that the process runs invisibly, so this may not even be a requirement. Aside from that, it's worth nothing that (a) the system account (`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`) does _not_ have the same privileges as the `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller` account, and, from what I can tell, you cannot use the latter with `psexec`; (b), the question is about launching a _scheduled task_ in the context of a different user account, which is not the same as _direct invocation of a process_ (mediated by `psexec`).